# Prevent page show before script is executed

Tags: javascript

I have may be simple question, but how is possible to make browser stop rendering page before script is fully executed and continue after? I need to include some javascript file into html page for example `loader.js` and in this file load another javascript file. I want to continue rendering page after all scripts are loading. Simply: start laoding page, load `loader.js` in `loader.js` load another js file/files and then show page. How can this be done? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When a browser reads a script tag it stops parsing HTML and interprets the Javascript. So all you need is to include the Javascript before the HTML i.e place the Javascript within the `<head></head>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

Load them synchronously, the first .js will load a file synchronously, the second should load the third file synchronously. And place your first js file at the top of your page in the `<head>` tag.